# C++ nested map with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, stl, smart-pointers

I'm currently learning c++ and focusing on the STL. I didn't find the answer to this problem, so here is the issue: how to set elements in the data structure `map<int, map<string, vector<unique_ptr>>>`? The following code with some comments illustrates this problem:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Used in the example
struct Resource {};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // I was able to get the following map running fine
  // int -> { string -> unique_ptr }
  map<int, map<string, unique_ptr<Resource>>> data;

  map<string, unique_ptr<Resource>> toBeInserted;
  toBeInserted["key"] = unique_ptr<Resource>(new Resource);
  // data[1] = toBeInserted; // error
  data[1] = std::move(toBeInserted); // ok


  // But the issue happens when it's a vector of unique_ptrs
  // int -> { string -> { [unique_ptr] } }
  map<int, map<string, vector<unique_ptr<Resource>>>> otherData;

  vector<unique_ptr<Resource>> list;
  list.push_back(unique_ptr<Resource>(new Resource));
  list.push_back(unique_ptr<Resource>(new Resource));

  map<string, vector<unique_ptr<Resource>>> _toBeInserted;
  _toBeInserted["key"] = std::move(list); // ok

  // But I cant insert _toBeInserted back to the original map.
  // The compilation errors are all related to the unique_ptr 
  otherData[1] = std::move(_toBeInserted); // Can't do this 
}
```

-- edit: link to the compilation erros: [ideone.com/hs3G8m](http://ideone.com/hs3G8m)

My question is how to initialize and add elements to the structure `map<int, map<string, vector<unique_ptr<T>>>>`. I'm using GCC 4.9 with c++11 flag. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `vector<unique_ptr<Resource>> list;`  I recommend to not name your variables the same as an STL class, i.e. `list`.

Comment: ... especially if you're the kind to do `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Here: http://ideone.com/hs3G8m

Comment: Why are you using `unique_ptr` here? If you put a `unique_ptr` in a `vector` then when you want to dereference it you would have to actually move it out first, since you're not allowed to make a duplicate one. It seems that `shared_ptr` is the appropriate type for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Same code, using `std::shared_ptr`:  http://ideone.com/ltSka8

Comment: In a pinch I suppose you could `std::swap(otherData[1],_toBeInserted);` instead, but probably not the answer you're looking for. Oddly, your code compiles on my OS X clang 3.5, but pukes as-described on Coliru with what *should* be the same toolchain and standard selection (`-std=c++11`).

Comment: In the code I had this problem, the map described is a member of class that manages some resources and performs some actions based on those resources. Originally it was just a vector of resources, but to find them it did a linear search in the list. I tried to optimize by nesting (does that makes sense?) the attributes of the resource in maps. The manager actually owns all resources it needs to perform it's tasks.

Comment: @WhozCraig Coliru's `clang++` seems to be using GCC's STL. OP's code actually compiles fine on both `clang++` and Intel's `icpc` with `-std=c++11` on Mac OS X. Both of these use Clang's STL. Seems like a bug in GCC's STL? (Also, I take back my comment regarding the validity of `unique_ptr` here: it's OK as long as OP doesn't try to 'alias' the pointer when pulling it out of the `map`)

Comment: This compiles for me with clang++ 3.4 as well as g++ 4.8.2 so I'd assume it is a compiler / standard library bug. However, I find it hard to imagine that a std::map of std::maps of std::vectors is actually an optimization of any kind. Are you aware, that there are algorithms to perform a binary search on a (sorted) vector?

Comment: I built the code with g++ 4.4 (-std=c++0x) and It compiles without issues. Should be something wrong in your setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see any problems with the code.
I have compiled it as

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 test.cpp
```

without any warnings using

```
gcc (GCC) 4.8.1
```

It looks like a compiler/STL bug.